# rails 4 edit for with different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having the following form in my profile/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @customer, url: {controller: :customer, action: :update} do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :username, value: @customer.username%>
<%= f.submit 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

And in my customer controller i have following method

```
def edit
    @customer = Customer.find session[:customer_id]
end

def update
      @customer.update(customer_params)
end

private
private
  def customer_params
    params[:customer]
  end
```

When i submit the form getting route error

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/customer/update"
```

I have added following line in route.rb then too facing same error

```
resources :profiles
  resources :customers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update action never defines @customer before you use the update method.  Try something like this in your update action:

```
@customer = Customer.find session[:customer_id]
@customer.update(customer_params)
```

Also, your customer params is not set correctly.  To get it to permit the items in the form, use the following:

```
def profile_params
      params.require(:customer).permit(:username)
end
```

Comment: Tried it getting error as `ActionController::ParameterMissing at /profile/edit param not found: customer`

Comment: my mistake, use def customer_params

Comment: can you post your customers table schema?

Comment: name,username,email,password,phone_number,country,state... my table schema. def customer_params also throwing same error

Comment: The goal of this form is for a user to update his/her username?

Comment: Also, are you using devise and is your customer model your user model i.e. do your users register for the site and login as customers?

Comment: Yes customer login through this

Comment: are you using devise?

Comment: NO I am not using device

Comment: Do my advice for the customer_params method and also change the controller object to CustomersController and the controller file to customers_controller.rb.  also, make sure your views are in the customers folder and make sure your model is just customer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug issues like these is to look at the output of 'rake routes' and see if the URL you are trying to call is present in the output.

If I have to take a guess...it seems like you will need to pass in the ID of the customer in the patch request..something like /customer/1/update where 1 is the id of the customer in your database

EDIT : actually just take out the url part of the form_for. I think that is what is throwing off rails. So your form_for should look like

```
<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
```

Comment: Ok once i tried the above format my url became `http://localhost:3000/customers/5` and throwing error as `ActionController::RoutingError at /customers/5/edit uninitialized constant CustomersController`

Comment: @Seting, I think you need to rename your controller to CustomersController ...i.e. customers_controller.rb :)

Answer (score 0):

change controller: :customer to controller: :customer`s`